# How to exit from wpf app

Tags: wpf, events

I have a WPF project that is part of the solution, it is "ProjectFilesSelector". A some project, named A. call ProjectFilesSelector as figure below:

!!! UPDATED:

`namespace ProjectFilesSelector
{
   ...
   public class ViewModel 
   {
        ...
        public ICommand cancel
        {
            get
            {
                return new WPFExtensions.RelayCommand(_ =>
                    {
                        this.window.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                        this.window.Close();

                    });
            }
        }

   }`

public partial class Window1 : Window, IDisposable
   {
        public Window1(ProjectTypes.Project pro)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
        var context = new ViewModel(this, new ATChecker.ViewModel.ProjectModel(pro));
        this.DataContext = context;
    }
```

...
   }

}

namespace ATCheckerView
{
    public class ViewerClientExt : INotifyPropertyChanged
    { 
        ...

`public ICommand CheckPrinciplies
    {
        get
        {
            var cmnd =
                new RelayCommand(project =>
                {
                    var proj = (ViewModel.ProjectModel)project;

                    ProjectFilesSelector.ViewModel dc;

                    using (var a = new ProjectFilesSelector.Window1(proj.project))
                    {
                        a.ShowDialog(); // cancel command was called
                        dc = (ProjectFilesSelector.ViewModel)a.DataContext;
                    }
                    ....
                    // some code 
                    // and I can still see the window of Window1. Why? 


                });`

Answer (score 1):

I don t think you want to exit the application. You may just want to close the window. 
The cancel button just set IsCancel to true. And for the ok button the best way is to create a event in the viewmodel to get up to the view.

Comment: isCancel? Where it is located? I tried a transfer Window object to Viewe model and in a Cancel/Ok button write some like: NOT, i added it to question